# QChar to ASCII to Int

Tags: c++, qt

Как перевести QChar в ASCII Int?

Comment: Например вызвать метод [`toLatin1`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#toLatin1)

Comment: @LLENN нужно, чтобы символ QChar выводился как код ASCII

Comment: А чем вам `char` не угоден то? А с этим вам поможет таблица `ASCII`.

Comment: @LLENN Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать метод [`toLatin1`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#toLatin1)

```cpp
int(toLatin1(QChar('1')));
```